# Django не загружает изображение со стилей

Tags: python, django

Django видит изображения в папках, проверял командой `./manage.py findstatic images/logo.png`, стиль подгрузился нормально, но в логах нет ни каких упоминаний о `logo.png`, ни ошибки ни чего, по урлу картинка открывается корректно `http://127.0.0.1:5000/images/logo.png`.

`settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, 'static/images'
)
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`main.css`

```
header .logo a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border: none;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url("/static/images/logo.png") no-repeat center;
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    font: 0/0 a;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: transparent;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Лог `main.css`

`[29/Jun/2020 08:17:51] "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 13542`

Код с шаблона `html`:

```
<header class="short-header">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Скрин Network в браузере:

[image: Скриншот]

Скрин ошибка в `Network`:

[image: Скрин ошибка в Network]

Сама картинка отображается на странице корректно `<img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="">`:

[image: Скриншот лого на странице]

При в ставке `<style>` прям в шаблон код отрабатывает, но необходимо что б все подгружалось через сам `css`, ниже пример с шаблона `html`:

```
{% load static %}

<style>
    header .logo a {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        outline: 0;
        border: none;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        background: url("{% static 'images/logo.png' %}") no-repeat center;
        background-size: 60px 60px;
        font: 0/0 a;
        text-shadow: none;
        color: transparent;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
</style>
```

Что может быть не так?

Comment: Если в логах нет запроса, то браузер не делает запрос. Как в html используется стиль?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">`, так лог показывает что код 200

Comment: @АндрейСаламов вы консоль браузера смотрели? Что в Netwoking и что в инспекторе элементов?

Comment: @АндрейСаламов во-первых, отвечайте не в коментариях, а исправляйте текст вопроса (кнопкой `править`). Во-вторых, мой вопрос в том, как используется стиль, а именно - css-то вы подгрузили, но вот есть ли элемент в html, к которому стиль с фоном применяется?

Comment: Да есть конечно, сейчас поправлю, и покажу что в консоле

Comment: Проверьте, как браузер разобрал `CSS`. Код `header .logo a {}` невалидный. Браузер мог скрыть эту ошибку и проигнорировать весь стиль (как следствие и загрузку фона).

Comment: Я думаю, дело в опечатке: `-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;ииььь `.

Comment: Проверил в валидаторе, не обнаружил ошибки, на счет опечатки, опечатка тут в стеке, в коде все как положено.

Comment: Из `network` видно, что браузер не делает запрос. Кроме того видно, что есть целых 7 ошибок (правый верхний угол). Проверьте, что это за ошибки.

Comment: Добавил скриншот ошибки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что css файл отдается, как есть и не обрабатывается движком шаблонов django. Т.е. теги шаблонов типа `{% url ... %}` или `{% static ... %}` никто не интерпретирует.

Рабочий способ это создать django view для того, чтобы css файл обрабатывался:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('path/to/main.css', TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='main.css',
        content_type='text/css')
    ),
    ...
]
```

Ну и включить в html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% url 'main.css' %}" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Это моя опечатка `</header>` в проекте закрыт корректно, у меня html + CSS + js проект скачан отдельно, и код корректно отрабатывает, проблема возникает в отображении картинки в Django